# How to submit multiple forms in one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `Event` show page where I display a particular event and on that event page I have a customer registration form for that event (`Customer` belongs_to `Event`).

Since I have two kinds of events, I have two separate forms for each individual type of event. One of them is submitted by a player, the other one is submitted by player's parent.

Now, on parent's form I display fields for the parent but I also want to have a `Add player` button, which would show a form for the player with different fields. It should be possible to add max 3 players. I know how to display this new form but how do I submit that kind of form to the controller? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (pseudo-code quality, not tested):

```
# model
class Event < ApplicationModel
  has_many :players
  acccepts_nested_attributes_for :players
end


#view
<% form_for @event do |f|%>
  # event inputs
  # ...
  <% f.fields_for :players %>
    # players inputs
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

You probably need a bit of JS *magic* to add up to 3 players.

- https://medium.com/@onyoo/why-accepts-nested-attributes-for-6ed190def58a
- https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for (Rails 4)
- https://medium.com/@oliviazyc/complex-nesting-forms-in-rails-631b369be0de